# Get Image file path from Image class type

Tags: c#, windows, image

I have a query regarding `C#` `Image class type`. Consider the following statement

```
Image img = Image.LoadFromFile(@"C:\1.jpg");
```

Question: How can I get the image file path from the `img` variable?

Guess:
I dont think we can have image path because, if we see the method LoadFromFile, it reads image from physical file path and loads it into memory byte by byte. Once its loaded it will be in img object. img object now will be independent of Image physical file on the disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess is correct, the image-object doesn't have a connection to the file after it's been loaded into memory. You need to store the path in a separate variable, or do something like this:

```
public class ImageEx
{
    public Image Image { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public ImageEx(string filename)
    {
        this.Image = Image.FromFile(filename);
        this.Filename = filename;
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        ImageEx img = new ImageEx(@"C:\1.jpg");

        Debug.WriteLine("Loaded file: {0}", img.Filename);
        Debug.WriteLine("Dimensions: {0}x{1}", img.Image.Width, img.Image.Height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following

```
 img.ImageUrl
```

Comment: I dont find that property. Am using Windows C# system.drawing.Image class